# Predicate Logic Translations

Tags: logic

I'm currently learning predicate logic in university. I am doing a few predicate translations and just wondering if I'm on the right track.

**A rectangle is a square unless its sides are different lengths.**

Rx = x is a rectangle

Sx = x is a square

Dx = x has different length sides

∀x(Rx ⊃ (Sx v Dx))

**For every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction.**

Ax = x is an action

Ry = y is an equal reaction

Oz = z is an opposite reaction

∀x(Ax ⊃ ∃y∃z(Ry & Oz))

**There is a barber who shaves all barbers who don’t shave themselves**

Bx = x is a barber

By = y is a barber

Sxy = x who shaves y

Syy = y who shaves y

∃x∀y(Bx & (By ⊃(Sxy & ~Syy)))

Answer (score 1):

> I am doing a few predicate translations and just wondering if I'm on the right track.

No.   Try first restating the English sentences with a sentencial logic structure.

For instance, "It is blue unless it is red" should be read as a conditional, "If it is not red, then it is blue."

> A rectangle is a square unless its sides are of different lengths.

For anything: *if* it is a rectangle, *then if* its sides are *not* of different lengths, *then* it is a square.

> For every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction.

For anything, there is something, if the former is an action then the later is an (re)action, the later is equal to the former, and the later is opposite to the former

(Note I: We are claiming the existence of something that is an equal-*and*-opposite reaction.)

(Note II: *Is Opposite To* and *Is Equal To* should be *bivariate* predicates)

> There is a barber who shaves all barbers who don’t shave themselves

There is something, for anything: the former is a barber and *if* the later is a barber *and* the later does not shave themselves, *then* the former shaves the later.

Comment: So for #1 would the correct translation be ∀x(~Dx ⊃ (Rx ⊃ Sx))?

Comment: Well... yes, although  $\forall x~(Rx\supset ({\sim}Dx\supset Sx))$ would be a more *direct* translation (they are equivalents, but we want to say "A rectangle is...").  @TateGreeves

Comment: Ok thanks. Now for #3 would the translation be ∃x∀y(Bx & ((By & ~Syy) ⊃ Sxy))? Thanks for the help it's much appreciated.